# HTML/mathjax on arXiv

Tags: formatting

have seen some HTML papers on [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/) in the past.

> is there a standard for HTML+mathjax or HTML+LaTeX papers on arxiv? examples?

basically am looking for a less complex version of a paper format that does not require full compiling with a latex compiler etc., somewhat like wordpress pages that allow some basic latex expressions, or like on stackexchange.

Comment: ps know this a bit unusual question, not sure where this question would go best on se. would it fly better on [academia.se]?